# What does it refer to in this sentence?

Tags: british-english

Armani's move into hotel business is considered the boldest by a luxury goods company, but "it" is not the first.
For what does it in "it's not the first refer to?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some ambiguity.

Either

(a) 'it' refers to Armani's move (compared to bold moves made by other luxury goods companies)

or

(b) 'it' refers to Armani's making the boldest move in the luxury goods market in more than one instance. I.e. Armani is consistently bolder than other companies.